# how to do a if in a export default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

i m a real newbie in web programming and i try to do a question-reponse in vue.js

```
export default {
 // I want to an if (character == "Passé" then do this steps")
  "steps": [

    {
      
      "id": 1,
      "background": jpg.village,
      "title": "Votre aventure épique commence ici. Pour découvrir la raison de ces terribles disparitions, il faudrait commencer à enquêter au plus vite. Cependant, vous vous apprêtiez à aller a la boutique pour acheter des équipements qui pourraient peut-être vous aider pour votre quête...",
      "actions": [
        {
          "description": "Aller à la boutique d'équipements",
          "path": 2
        },

 "characters": [
    {
      "class": "Passé",
      "description": "“ A l'antiquité, la puissance ecrasait la défense. Attaquez et vous survivrez”",
      "stats": {
        "luck": 5,
        "power": 20,
        "agility": 4,
        "health": 85
      }
    },
    {
      "class": "Present",
      "description": "“ Aujourd'hui, nous sommes dans une ère ou la puissance et la defense sont egales, le seul frein.. La mobilité. ”",
      "stats": {
        "luck": 4,
        "power": 10,
        "agility": 2,
        "health": 150
      }
    },

    }
  ]
```

but he doesn't like it, i saw other tutoriels but they never use it in a "export defaut"

Thanks :)

Comment: Because your brackets don't match. Check the opening and closing brackets *(properly indent the lines)* and fix the mismatch.

Comment: oh i just did'nt put all my code, but that function without the if

Comment: Oh, I see. `if (character == "Passé"` does that mean that `character` will never change while the program is running? Because once you've executed that line and exported some structure you'll never get back to this condition again.

Comment: And take a look at the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for inline conditions

Comment: yes! thanks i will see that

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are importing it in another module using curly brackets. When default exporting, it should be imported **without** curly brackets.

Wrong:

```
import {something} from someModule
```

Right:

```
import something from someModule
```

Comment: Of coarse I read it, it does not provide much information except that "export default" is causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to add inline optional properties to an object:

```
export default {
  ...(character !== 'Passé' ? {} : { steps: [<your steps array>] })
}
```

The `...` is called a spread operator. It will expand the properties of the variable attached to it into the parent object (also works for arrays). In this case, we are adding either `{}` (nothing) or `{ steps: [] }` based on your condition.

You can also do `steps: character !== 'Passé' ? []  : [ <steps array> ]`
This will make it so that `steps` will always be defined on your object as an array.

Both of these will work.